# Sort of Array<[string, number]> string as a date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting

I have a list `Array<[string, number]>` I want to sort this list By the string as a date ASC
my list is like:

```
0: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:38", 100]
1: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:48", 89]
2: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:36", 100]
3: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:42", 100]
4: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:52", 78]
5: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:40", 100]
6: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:50", 89]
7: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:46", 100]
8: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:56", 78]
9: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:44", 100]
10: (2) ["01/09/2020 23:54", 78]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You provided an objective and some pseudo data but haven't shown us what you have tried or where you are having specific problems

Comment: @charlietfl I want to sort this liste by date I don't know how

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[].sort((a,b)=>a-b)` like below:

```js
var dateData=[["01/09/2020 23:38", 100],["01/09/2020 23:48", 89],["01/09/2020 23:36", 100],["01/09/2020 23:42", 100]];

dateData.sort((a,b)=>new Date([a[0]]) - new Date([b[0]]));
console.log(dateData);
```